# Is there a way to multiple filter Dataframe in Python-Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

looking for some way to filter my Data frame by few criteria's (Dataframe for example:

```
id  Arrest  Shift_num  Description
0   True    20         Weapon
1   False   25         unarmed
2   True    30         Weapon
```

I would like to get DF with:
Description == Weapon and `shift_num >= 25` and `arrest == True` (for example)

after few tries , that was my way, but i think it can be better than this :

```
arrest=(df.Arrest == True)
shift=(df.Shift_num >= 25)
weap= (df['Description'] == 'weapon')

print(df[arrest & shift & weap])
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `df[df['Arrest'].eq(True) & df['Shift_num'].ge(25) & df['Description'].eq('weapon')]`

Comment: Yours looks good to me.

Comment: Your solution is typically how it's done in Pandas. It may be slightly better do apply all three masks at once rather than storing each as a variable.

Comment: See Boolean Indexing in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html?highlight=boolean%20index#boolean-indexing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [df.query](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) (a bonus: it uses `numexpr` which is very optimized!):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Arrest": [True, False, True], 
                   "Shift_num": [20, 25, 30], 
                   "Description": ["Weapon", "unarmed", "Weapon"]})

df.query("Arrest & Shift_num >= 25 & Description == 'Weapon'")
```

Output:

```
   Arrest  Shift_num Description
2    True         30      Weapon
```

Some notes:

- Don't forget to 'quote' strings
- The variable names that can be used are from the DataFrame scope (without needing to prefix using `df`)
- Use `~Arrest` when you want NOT arrested
- You can use `@` to refer to a variable in the scope (i.e. not in the df)

I encouraged you to read about [numexpr](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr).

Comment: Amazing,Thank you very much :))))Appreciate it

Comment: @MaxBoyar You're welcome! Feel free to accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try slicing:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Arrest':[True,False,True],'Shift_num':[20,25,30],'Description':['Weapon','unarmed','Weapon']})

df.loc[(df['Description'] == 'Weapon') & (df['Shift_num'] > 25) & (df['Arrest'] == True)]
```

Answer (score 1):

What you've got works. Here is a one liner that may be slightly more efficient. Since `Arrest` is a boolean field, you can evaluate it directly instead of using the `== True`.

```
In [5]: df[(df.Description == 'Weapon') & (df.Shift_num >= 25) & (df.Arrest)] 
Out[5]: 
   id  Arrest  Shift_num Description
2   2    True         30      Weapon
```

Comment: Thanks,Worked for me ,appreciate it :)